# Software for technical drawings

Tags: drawing, educational

I'm looking for software to create technical drawings, add forces to simple objects, be able to create parabolic velocity profiles, draw surface loads e.g.

The software should be free or at least free with a .edu mail. This is for a collection of different approaches for problems (to create drafts along with it) and I might could use it for my thesis. So it doesn't need to be the most advanced or complex software.